# Pase JSON Complejo DART

Tags: flutter, dart

Amigos estoy en un proyecto donde necesito acceder a la información de un JSON bastante complejo.

[image: JSON Extraído de la API]
Este es el de los episodios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Necesito acceder a las propiedades de "season", "info" y "episodes" pero no logro como hacerlo.

Cree el modelo desde quicktype.io y estoy usando el siguiente parse para acceder a los datos:

```
class SeasonsProvider {
  final String url =
      'url_api';

  Future<List<Season>> cargarTemporadaSerie(serieId) async {

final String urlfinal = url + '${serieId}';
final resp = await http.get(urlfinal);

final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
final List<Season> seasons = new List();

if (decodedData == null) return [];
decodedData.forEach((nombre, season) {
  final seasonTemp = Season.fromJson(season);
  seasonTemp.name = nombre;
  season.add(seasonTemp);
});
return seasons;
```

}
    }

El problema es que no hace una conversión correcta del formato del JSON y no puedo obtener los datos, obtengo la siguiente excepción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener una lista con el parámetro "name"

Comment: haz un print the `resp.body` , agregálo a la pregunta, y también agrega la clase Seasons

Comment: No pones las otras clases, Season , SeasonsInfo, Episode , puede existir error en cualquiera de esas, lo mejor sería que agregues un try /catch aquí  var temporadas = (json.decode(resp.body) as List)
        .map((f) => new Seasons.fromJson(f))
        .toList();  para que veas donde va el error

Comment: Cambien un poco la forma de obtener los datos, y ya puedo ingresar a los datos de la Season, pero no puedo exportar la lista de nombres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné con el siguiente codigo:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    if (decodedData == null) return [];
    var decodedDataFinal=decodedData['seasons'] as List;
    var seasons = decodedDataFinal.map((f) => new Season.fromJson(f))
        .toList();
    return seasons;
```